# Maintain image aspect ratio while loading

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a simple web page.
I would like to know if there's a way to specify the ratio of an image, so the page is rendered correctly even while loading the image.

Now my code is:

```
<img src="icon.png" width="100%" />
```

While loading the page the height of the image is 0.

I would like to know if something like this exists:

```
<img src="icon.png" width="100%" ratio="0.5" />
```

So, if it is possible, the image would have the correct height even before the image is loaded.

My page currently doesn't use javascript, so it would be appreciated an answer that doesn't use it.

Comment: The easiest way to keep or scale the ratio is set a height of auto and adjust your width accordingly - Have you tried `img { width: 100%; height: auto; }`?

Comment: Once the image is loaded, the ratio is perfect. The problem is that while the browser loads the image, the height is 0.

Comment: If you know what the width is, use that value by `px` absolute length, If not, you may need to handle it at server-side in order to get the dimensions of the image and add `width` attribute/value pair into `<img>` element. Because even by using JavaScript you have to load the image at first which doesn't make sense in this particular case.

Comment: I know the ratio of the image: it is fixed at 0.5

Comment: If you're simply concerned about what it looks like while it is loading, maybe use a smaller byte img file in the LOWSRC: <img src="icon.png" lowsrc="icon_lowres.png">, it'll zip right in, giving your bigger file time to load.